# Find multiple words and print the next numbers within a single line

Tags: awk, grep

I saved a single line sql result to a file.

```
AA 10 BB 20 DD 14 GG 14
```

I want to count the numbers next to each words and save it as variables.
And if there's none(like CC) it should be counted as 0.

aCnt=10
bCnt=20
cCnt=0

Can 'grep' or 'awk' do this?

Comment: How do you know that `CC` should be zero? What about `ZL`, `NA`, `PQ`, or any other word that does not exist in your output?

Comment: @Kusalananda wow. At first I didn't think of that as a problem because I was only dealing with pre-determined names. But now that I have to deal with undefined names, it's causing troubles. I need some awk soccery.

Comment: (1) What do you mean by “count”? (2) Can a “word” appear more than once, as in `AA 5 AA 12 BB 2000 BB 21`? (3) Will the numbers always be positive integers? Or can there be `FF 1.5 NN -42 PP 3.14159 ZZ 0`? (4) Will the “words” always be in alphabetic order? (5) Please respond to Kusalananda’s comment — will the “words” always be `AA`, `BB`, `CC` … `ZZ`, or can there be `A`, `ZL`, `FOO` or `F17`? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be better off with an associative array instead of a bunch of individual variables:

```bsh
line="AA 10 BB 20 DD 14 GG 14"
read -ra words <<< "$line"

declare -A cnt
for ((i = 0; i < ${#words[@]}; i += 2)); do
    label=${words[i]} 
    num=${words[i+1]}
    cnt[${label:0:1}]=$num
done

declare -p cnt      # => declare -A cnt=([G]="14" [D]="14" [B]="20" [A]="10" )
```

Now:

```bsh
letter=A
echo "$letter count is ${cnt[$letter]:-0}"  # => A count is 10
letter=C
echo "$letter count is ${cnt[$letter]:-0}"  # => C count is 0
```

---

With individual variables, we can use `declare` for "dynamic" variable names:

```bsh
for a in {a..z}; do
    declare "${a}Cnt=0"
done
line="AA 10 BB 20 DD 14 GG 14"
declare -l letter     # lowercase
while [[ $line =~ ([A-Z]+)" "([0-9]+)(.*) ]]; do
    letter=${BASH_REMATCH[1]:0:1}
    declare "${letter}Cnt=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    line=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
done
```

Now we have:

```bsh
$ set | grep '.Cnt'
aCnt=10
bCnt=20
cCnt=0
dCnt=14
eCnt=0
fCnt=0
gCnt=14
hCnt=0
iCnt=0
jCnt=0
kCnt=0
lCnt=0
mCnt=0
nCnt=0
oCnt=0
pCnt=0
qCnt=0
rCnt=0
sCnt=0
tCnt=0
uCnt=0
vCnt=0
wCnt=0
xCnt=0
yCnt=0
zCnt=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Equally crazy `awk`.....since that's the tag

```
awk -vRS=" " '{a=tolower(substr($0,1,1)); getline; aa[a]=$0}
     END{for (a=97; a<=122; a++) {A=sprintf("%c",a); print A"Cnt="aa[A]+0}}' file
```

Break records `RS` on  , an associative array and a bit of jiggery pokery with the string characters

```
aCnt=10
bCnt=20
cCnt=0
dCnt=14
eCnt=0
fCnt=0
gCnt=14
hCnt=0
```